# issues with r lang for r 3.3

Tags: r, rlang

If I use:

```
tools::checkMD5sums("rlang")
```

I get:

```
[1] NA
```

I used:

```
install.packages('C:/DataScience/zipped_packages/rlang_0.3.0.tar.gz', repos = NULL, type="source")
```

in an attempt to install an older version for R 3.3. Is there anything I can do fix this? I cannot upgrade R. Thanks!

Comment: So the issue is just that the MD5 sum can't be checked? You don't get an error at all when running `install.packages`? If that works, does `system.file("MD5", package="rlang")` return a path? Where did you get the `rlang_0.3.0.tar.gz` file from?

Comment: Thanks. I got this from https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/rlang/ and I will check the rest tomorrow.  Btw is there a way to figure which version of the package works with which R version? Thanks.